# Question about the rate of convergence.

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson, fixed-point-iteration

The question: Consider a function such that $f(x)$, $f'(x)$, and $f''(x)$ are continuous and bounded on a certain interval containing $\alpha$. Let $f(\alpha) = 0$ , $f'(\alpha) = 0$, and $f''(\alpha) \neq 0$. Find the rate of convergence of the iterative method:

$x_{n+1} = x_{n} - 2\frac{f(x_{n})}{f'(x_{n})}$ which $n \geq 0 $.

The attempt: I have no idea how to start on this problem to be honest. Can someone give me a head start on this problem? 
Thank you very much!!

Comment: Do you know the proof of quadratic convergence when $f'(\alpha) \neq 0$? Carry out the same steps and see what the estimates say.

Comment: (For example, one such step is to write $f(x_n)=f'(\alpha)(x_n-\alpha)+\frac{1}{2} f''(\alpha)(x_n-\alpha)^2 + o((x_n-\alpha)^2)$.)